# change domain and subdomain get No route found for " GET / "

Tags: symfony

I changed the domain and server name in my virtual host for my Symfony project and I get No route found for all my routes, while all my routes operate with the old domain and subdomain
any help well be very appreciated

Comment: Have you change your vhost and cleared your cache?

Comment: yes i do that, it's very weird

Comment: Please show your vhost config and any changes to your symfony-app (if any). Did you search for the old subdomain in your configs-folder?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 dev.me api.dev.me admin.dev.me www.dev.me

Comment: in fact the domain and subdomain are in the parameters file, so I just do change over parameters.yml files, I did a search for the old and found nothing